# How to ignore all external assemblies in NDepend

Tags: ndepend

Having started to use NDepend I'm frustrated by being cluttered with issues related to nuget packages and external dlls.

For example I'm looking at 400 issues of >>Interface name should begin with a 'I'<< just because I have to reference Microsoft.Office.* namespaces in an external dll, and apparently MS didn't feel like naming interfaces with an I when they made that code.

That's just one example of issues from external Nuget packages and elsewhere cluttering my ability to clean up my own code.

I've already made sure the rules are using "JustMyCode" domain, but apparently that doesn't help in preventing analysis of external assemblies.

Is there a "notmycode" query/rule I can make to make NDepend ignore **every single one** of the external assemblies, or do I have to make and maintain a list of exact assemblies by fullname and make a notmycode query on those?

I want to optimize and clean my own code - not thousands of lines of code over which I have no control.

Comment: what if you remove the external dll(s) from NDepend > Project Properties > Code to Analyze > Application Assemblies ?

Comment: Hi. They are already removed from "Application Assemblies", but listed as 54 "Third party Assemblies", and apparently, that's enough to still be counted for JustMyCode Issues?

Comment: The rule *Interface name should begin with a 'I'* operates on JustMyCode.Types, which is a subset of Application.Types, disjoint from ThirdParty.Types, hence third-party types cannot be matched by this rule

Comment: Moreover in the next version we're adding the namespace(s) Microsoft.Office.* in notmycode to make sure such issues will never popup again.

Comment: Thank you. I really like NDepend by the way. Steep learning curve, but I already feel it helps create better code.

Comment: Thanks Kasper, the team is glad to read about your good experience, be sure we keep up the good work :)